# How do I select a column in data grid view?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, multiple-columns

I can only select rows at the moment but I want to select both columns and rows in data grid view. How would I do this?

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987193/datagridview-how-to-select-an-entire-column-and-deselect-everything-else).

Comment: What kind of forms? Windows Forms? Web Forms? WPF? SilverLight?

Comment: Do you mean select rows and columns programmatically or allowing the user to do so?