# DataGridView OnRowPostPaint draw

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Actually, my code is "selecting hover" all the line, when i have the mouse over the cell, but, i want to change it, i want to select all the **column**, not the line.

[Data Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpSQW.png)

How can i manage it?

My code is:

```
    protected override void OnRowPostPaint(DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRowPostPaint(e);
        if (this.RectangleToScreen(e.RowBounds).Contains(MousePosition))
        {
            using (var b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black)))
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.MediumVioletRed))
            {
                var r = e.RowBounds;
                r.Width -= 1;
                r.Height -= 1;

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.RowBounds.X, e.RowBounds.Y,e.RowBounds.Width,  e.RowBounds.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, r);

            }


        }
    }
```

I can find the same method, but to draw vertically...

Thank you

Comment: on mouseover you want to select all the cells in the column being hovered? Is that it?

Comment: yes! instead of selecting all the row, i want all the cells in the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You just want to select entire column while mouse is over any cell then You don't have to use OnRowPostPaint event , You can make the selection mode for the entire grid to select entire column instead of only one cell or entire row but to do that You need to make the SortMode for the Columns set to anything other than Automatic. here is how to do it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
  {
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
  }
  dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect;
}
```

then use either OnCellMouseEnter or OnCellMouseMove events to select whole column like this:

```
private void OnCellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowIndex == -1 || e.ColumnIndex == -1)
    return;
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
}
```

refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987193/datagridview-how-to-select-an-entire-column-and-deselect-everything-else) for more information on selecting entire column.

Comment: actually i dont want to "select" the cells, only "hover" the cells in the column with another color...

Comment: you can check the updated answer of @blaze_125 , I tested it and it behaves just like what you asked and also is very fast in rendering , you should mark his answer as answered otherwise add clarification in comments of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want but maybe this example can get you started:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {

        Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + 1,
            e.CellBounds.Y + 1, e.CellBounds.Width - 4,
            e.CellBounds.Height - 4);

        using (
            Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.GridColor),
            backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
        {
            using (Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush))
            {
                // Erase the cell.
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);

                // Draw the grid lines (only the right and bottom lines;
                // DataGridView takes care of the others).
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left,
                    e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right - 1,
                    e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1,
                    e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1,
                    e.CellBounds.Bottom);

                // Draw the inset highlight box.
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, newRect);

                // Draw the text content of the cell, ignoring alignment.
                if (e.Value != null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString((String)e.Value, e.CellStyle.Font,
                        Brushes.Crimson, e.CellBounds.X + 2,
                        e.CellBounds.Y + 2, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The example comes from this page [learn.microsoft.com DataGridView.OnCellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

This will select all the cells within the hovered column... though it's not really clear what you are asking for.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DatagridViewSelectAllCells_58842788
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add($"col1_{i}", $"col2_{i}");
            }
            dataGridView1.CellMouseEnter += DataGridView1_CellMouseEnter;
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)//don't do anything if the rowheader is being hovered
            {
                return;
            }
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 1 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex)//don't do anything if the column is already selected
            {
                return;
            }
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();//clear the current selection

            //select all the cells in that hovered column
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, i].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here's an updated answer for just changing the color of the cells

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace DatagridViewSelectAllCells_58842788
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static Color originalColor;
        static int highlightedCol = -1;
        static DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
            dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add($"col1_{i}", $"col2_{i}");
            }
            dataGridView1.CellMouseEnter += DataGridView1_CellMouseEnter;
            dataGridView1.CellMouseLeave += DataGridView1_CellMouseLeave;

            dataGridView1[1, 4].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen;
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //WithCellStyle(sender, e, "Leave");
            WithDefaultStyle(sender, e, "Leave");
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //WithCellStyle(sender, e, "Enter");
            WithDefaultStyle(sender, e, "Enter");
        }


        /*
         * to handle cells that have specific style attributes
         * like cell dataGridView1[1, 4]
         * there would be more to this to keep track of multiple different cell styles on the Leave side of thing
         * but that's up to you to handle if you have a need for it.
         */
        private static void WithCellStyle(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e, string eType)
        {
            switch (eType)
            {
                case "Enter":
                    if (originalColor == null)
                    {
                        originalColor = ((Control)sender).BackColor;//store the color for leave event
                    }
                    highlightedCol = e.ColumnIndex;//set which column is highlighted for leave event

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1[highlightedCol, i].Style.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Leave":
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1[highlightedCol, i].Style.BackColor = originalColor;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        /*
         * if you only have default styles
         */
        private static void WithDefaultStyle(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e, string eType)
        {
            switch (eType)
            {
                case "Enter":
                    if (originalColor == null)
                    {
                        originalColor = ((Control)sender).BackColor;//store the color for leave event
                    }
                    highlightedCol = e.ColumnIndex;//set which column is highlighted for leave event

                    //change color of all the cells
                    dataGridView1.Columns[highlightedCol].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;//set the new color
                    break;
                case "Leave":
                    //per defaultstyle
                    dataGridView1.Columns[highlightedCol].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = originalColor;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i dont want to "select" the cells, only "hover" the cells in the column with another color...